# query that groups by a substring, returning the substring result and ordering by aggregates on the group

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax

So far I have this query

```
select count(*) as howMany,sum(Duration) as totalTime 
from [Tmp].[dbo].[tmp2] 
group by SUBSTRING(TextData,1,25)
```

which works fine to return two columns: howMany and totalTIme. I would like it to also return a column which contains t he results of SUBSTRING(TextData,1,25) which is the same for each group. However I am not sure how to modify the query to accomplish this.

I would also like the results ordered by totalTime, but the following attempt fails to compile

```
select * 
from (select count(*) as howMany,sum(Duration) as totalTime 
      from [Tmp].[dbo].[tmp2] 
      group by SUBSTRING(TextData,1,25) ) 
order by totalTime;
```

Comment: Am I missing something about your requirement? Just add `SUBSTRING(TextData, 1, 25)` into the `SELECT` list directly, alongside the other two aggregate functions.

Comment: Your second query is probably failing to compile because you need to add a table alias to the subquery in your `FROM` clause. (telling us the error would have made this easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select SUBSTRING(TextData,1,25),
    count(*) as howMany,
    sum(Duration) as totalTime 
from [Tmp].[dbo].[tmp2] 
group by SUBSTRING(TextData,1,25)
order by 3 --3rd column
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTRING(TextData,1,25) as textdata, count(*) as howMany,sum(Duration) as totalTime
from [Tmp].[dbo].[tmp2] 
group by SUBSTRING(TextData,1,25)
order by sum(duration)
```

I beleive you can just add the substring bit to the select statement and add the sum in the order by.  It defaults to ascending, put desc at the end of the statement to reverse that